# Easy string switch and case function not working

Tags: php

I can't figure out why this isn't working, and I know it's because of ssome simple stupid mistake.

Could you please help me out?

```
$p = 'aM';

function FormatPeriod($p) {
 $periodFormated = 'null';
 switch($p){
   case "am": $periodFormated = "AM"; break;
   case "Am": $periodFormated = "AM"; break;
   case "aM": $periodFormated = "AM"; break;
   case "pm": $periodFormated = "PM"; break;
   case "Pm": $periodFormated = "PM"; break;
   case "pM": $periodFormated = "PM"; break;
     default: $periodFormated = 'fail';
    }
  return $periodFormated;
 }

$periodFormated = FormatDate($p);
```

Sadly, the output is "aM".

Why didn't the string change to "AM"?

~Thank you.

Comment: This code has typos. Fix them first so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Is `FormatDate == FormatPeriod` ?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function FormatDate()`. Have you completely disabled error reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need is

```
$p = 'am';
echo strtoupper($p);
```

if it is a user input you just need to add one more check

```
$p = strtolower($p);
if ($p == 'am' || $p == 'pm')
{
   $p = strtoupper($p);
}
else
{
   echo 'fail';
}
```

and you are calling different function to format. You should call `FormatPeriod` and you are calling `FormatDate`

Comment: My code is for a user input scenario.
So what if $p = 'xq'? I want it to become 'fail'.

Comment: The FormatDate was the problem. I've been staring at my code for too long, could't see that no matter how many times I reread it. Thank you.

Comment: @RickRyan: Which I already spotted out with my initial answer

Answer (score 0):

This code is terrible :)!

You do not need to check each case, simple convert string to uppercase.

```
$p = 'aM';

function FormatPeriod($p) {
    $periodFormated = strtoupper($p) ;
    return $periodFormated;
 }

$periodFormated = FormatPeriod($p);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            function FormatPeriod($p) {
             $periodFormated = strtoupper(trim($p));    //trim extra spaces and convert to uppercase
             if($periodFormated!='AM' && $periodFormated!='PM') //check if it is not AM or PM
                return 'fail';  //then return 'fail'
             else
                return $periodFormated; //otherwise return AM or PM
             }

            //Testing
            echo FormatPeriod('am') . '<br />';
            echo FormatPeriod('Am') . '<br />';
            echo FormatPeriod('aM') . '<br />';
            echo FormatPeriod(' am ') . '<br />';
            echo FormatPeriod('a am') . '<br />';
```